# Relevance of Fermat Primes outside construction of n-gons

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory

I recently came across the concept of Fermat Primes in the construction of n-gons and the cyclotomic equation. Apart from their presence in the situation mentioned above, are Fermat primes relevant nowadays in anything else?

Comment: Corrected, thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure they are used anywhere seriously, but Fermat primes can be used to prove there are infinitely many primes, by showing that any pair of Fermat numbers are relatively prime. If $d\mid 2^{2^k}+1$ then $2^{2^k}\equiv -1\pmod d.$ Then for $n>k,$ $$2^{2^n}=\left(2^{2^k}\right)^{2^{n-k}}\equiv\left(-1\right)^{2^{n-k}}\equiv 1\pmod d.$$ So when $d\mid 2^{2^n}+1,$ too, then $+1\equiv -1\pmod{d},$ or $d\mid 2.$ But since the Fermat numbers are odd, that means $d=1.$ . However, that proof works also works using $a^{2^k}+1,$ for even $a.$

Comment: It may be worth noting that the Fermat primes are a fairly natural object to study, despite the double-exponential definition: they are in fact the only primes of the form $2^n+1$, which makes them “dual” to Mersenne primes.

Answer (score 0):

There has been some recent work on exploiting the extremely simple multiplicative structure and the ease in which mod $F_n$ can be implemented on a computer.  See for instance, [Fermat Number Transform](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-0-387-21850-2_15).